# assigning true/false to std::string: what's going on?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, g++, std

I was testing a c++11 compiler on my source code and it caught an error in one of my functions that I would have expected my non c++11 compiler to catch as well. I was returning false from a function that has a return type of std::string... Here's the code that demonstrates the problem

```
#include <iostream>

int main ( )
{
    std::string str = false;

    std::cerr << "'" << str << "'" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


$ g++ test.cpp -W -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
Aborted
```

I'm very surprised that this code compiles with no problems. I suspect from the exception description is that the compiler is converting a false to 0 and then to NULL and uses that as a char * to try and construct the string..

However, when I switch false to true, here's what I get:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -W -Wall -Wextra
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5: error: conversion from ‘bool’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ requested
```

That's a more reasonable result, in my opinion.

Can someone please clarify why this seemingly inconsistent behaviour happens? That is, `std::string a = false` compiles, but throws an exception, and `std::string a = true` doesn't compile.

EDIT:

For reference, here's an error generated with g++ 4.7 with -std=c++11 for the false case:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5:23: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type for argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ [-Wconversion-null]
```

It does accept NULL though as CashCow suggests

Comment: Funny conversion sequence, false is a valid null pointer constant since its integral and converts to null opinter

Comment: What you posted is *not* an error, it's a *warning*. C++11 didn't fix anything wrt false -> null pointer constant.

Comment: @Xeo As I commented on your post, good catch :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rather a horrible implicit conversion and lack of type-safety.

`std::string` takes a constructor from a pointer
false degrades to 0 which becomes a null pointer.

and you cannot pass a null pointer to the constructor of std::string.

Incidentally whilst you use = it is a constructor not an assignment you are performing here.

Your "strict" g++ C++11 compiler however nicely caught the error for you at compile time.

And it won't work with true because that is never able to represent a NULL pointer. C++11 has nullptr. If you tried:

`std::string str = nullptr;`

your C++11 compiler would probably compile it and then you'd get a runtime error.

Comment: Why is true generating an error? I mean following this logic, it could convert it to 1 and treat that as an address. Or is 0 treated specially because of NULL?

Comment: Yes, 0 is a special case because of NULL. Not sure what happens with the strict C++11 compiler if you pass in NULL instead of nullptr, because that would break existing code all-over, but false certainly could be caught.

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly as you say, `false` can be converted to a valid null pointer constant (sadly so).

`true`, however, is not a null pointer constant and can't be converted to one and as such can't be converted to a pointer and fails to compile.

`§4.5 Integral promotions [conv.prom] p4`

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, **with `false` becoming zero** and `true` becoming one.

`§4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr] p1`:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type **that evaluates to zero** or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Since the `false` is a literal, it's also an integral constant expression, and after promotion indeed evaluates to zero.

***Note that this has not changed in C++11.*** In fact, the above quotes are from the C++11 standard. What you get with GCC 4.7 is just a *warning*. It's an optional diagnostic that your compiler decided to hint at, since it's always wrong and a bug.

Comment: Good catch on the warning, my original code also had -Werror, which converted it to an error and broke the build.

Comment: @vmpstr For some errors, "saved the build" might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It is a subtle issue that I may not fully understand.

The basic rule is that anything that has a value of `0` may be considered a valid null pointer. Therefore, `false` can be used in contexts requiring a pointer, like `char const*`.

However, the `std::string` constructor from a `char const*` explicitly requires a non-null pointer (and here you are fortunate to get an exception).

On the other hand, `true` is non-`0`, and so cannot be treated as a pointer. Thus you get a proper diagnostic.

---

This issue is compounded by the introduction of `constexpr` in C++11, which was raised by [Richard Smith](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1362):

```
struct S { constexpr S(): n() {} int n; };
```

here, `S().n` is evaluated to `0` statically (`constexpr` requirement) and thus may degenerate into a pointer, while in C++03 it was of type `int`. This is rather unfortunate and if you have:

```
std::true_type buggy(void*);
std::false_type buggy(int);
```

Then `decltype(buggy(S().n))` returns `true_type` for C++11 but `false_type` with C++03, a rather unfortunate change in semantics.

Richard's proposal is to change this from an implicit conversion to a standard conversion to help in this case, however I don't think that it would help much in yours.

Clang has warnings available for those weird conversions: `-Wbool-conversions`.

Comment: My jaw literally dropped at that point in the presentation. :(

Answer (score 3):

[Xeo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671195/166389) is correct up-to and including C++11.

In C++ 14, the relevant text in `§4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr] p1` was changed:

> A *null pointer constant* is an **integer literal (2.14.2)** with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`

(Bold emphasis by me)

So `false` remains an **integral constant expression** via `§4.5 Integral promotions [conv.prom] p4`, it is not a **integer literal**:
`§2.14.2 Integer literals [lex.icon] p1`:

> An *integer literal* is a sequence of digits that has no period or exponent part, with optional separating single quotes that are ignored when determining its value.

---

[gcc 4.5](https://godbolt.org/g/H0ebVz) warns about this, and [gcc 6.1](https://godbolt.org/g/GnmHHY) holds this as an error, irrespective of the `-std=c++1?` flag.

[Visual C++ 19.22.27905 from Visual Studio 2019 16.2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/BaQygL) happily compiles it, so that's not C++14-compliant. I couldn't find an open Microsoft Visual Studio Developer Community issue, so I [lodged one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46351/integer-constant-expressions-implicitly-convert-in.html), which is marked as fixed in Visual Studio 2019 16.4.

---

This issue was raised to the ISO C++ Standards Committee as [CWG1448](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1448) in 2012 and fixed as part of the resolution of [CWG903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903) (raised in 2009 but resolved in 2013).

The change to the standard wording is visible at [CWG903 Value-dependent integral null pointer constants](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/878a6dc4bd50b6eee45dc51fc1e38a9b829679ac) which added the following block of text to the list of differences from C++03 to the current standard:
`§C2.2 Clause 4: standard conversions [diff.cpp03.conv]`

> **Change:** Only literals are integer null pointer constants
>
> **Rationale:** Removing surprising interactions with templates and constant expressions
>
> **Effect on original feature:** Valid C++ 2003 code may fail to compile or produce different results in this International Standard, as the following example illustrates:
>
> `````
> void f(void *); // #1 
> void f(...); // #2
> template<int N> void g() {
>  f(0*N); // calls #2; used to call #1
> }````
> `````

Interestingly, this conversion was noted in-passing as weird in [CWG97](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#97) but wasn't the point of the issue so apparently nothing was done.

> [...] we have the anomalous notion that `true` and `false` are not constant expressions.
>
> Now, you may argue that you shouldn't be allowed to convert `false` to a pointer. But [...]